# Holder continuous functions embedded in Sobolev

Tags: sobolev-spaces, uniform-continuity, holder-spaces

For simplicity, I will consider $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, where $1<p<\infty$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ is open and bounded. I am able to show that
\begin{equation}
|u(x)-u(y)| \leq |x-y|^{1-1/p} \lVert u'\rVert_{L^p(\Omega)}
\end{equation}
for all $x,y\in\Omega$. Next, I want to show that the set of Holder continuous functions with Holder exponent $1-1/p$ is continuously embedded in $W^{1,p}$. To do so, I was told to prove that there exists a uniformly continuous function $v$ such that $u=v$ in almost every $x,y\in\Omega$.

I am confused what I really want to do to find $v$. Can I say $v$ is a function such that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x\neq y} \frac{|v(x)-v(y)|}{|x-y|^{1-1/p}} = \lVert u'\rVert_{L^p(\Omega)}
\end{equation}
for all $x,y\in\Omega$? Then I know Holder continuous functions are uniformly continuous, but is $v=u$ a.e?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the inclusion backwards: For instance the function $f(t)=|t|^{1/2}$ is Holder continuous in, say, $\Omega=(-1,1)$ but $f'(t)=t^{-1/2}\notin L^2(\Omega)$, therefore the inclusion $C^{0,1/2} \to W^{1,2}$ fails.

To prove that every $u\in W^{1,p}$ has a (locally absolutely) continuous representative see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248924/u-in-w1-p0-1-is-equal-a-e-to-an-absolutely-continuous-function).

Comment: Is it actually known whether an inequality like that postulated by the OP can possibly hold for some Sobolev space of fractional order?

Comment: @DelioMugnolo: An in-depth answer is not suitable for a comment, but basically yes: For instance, on a cube where you can use Fourier series and the Littlewood-Paley characterizations of both spaces (we use the Bessel potential definition of Sobolev, although similar embeddings hold for the Gagliardo seminorm ones) we have that, locally $C^\alpha$ embedds in $H^{s,p}$ for any $\alpha>s>0$ and $1<p<\infty$. A global embedding can't hold for scaling reasons, and morally it's the best (up to the endpoint) that we can expect:

Comment: Trading $L^p$ derivatives for $L^\infty$ ones costs $n/p$ of them, the other way around is for free, as long as we're on a bounded domain.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. Do you know a reference?