# Weak derivative of $|x|$ not in $W^{1,p}(-1, 1)$, another possible solution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm referring to the question presented here: [Weak derivative of $u(x)=|x|$ not belong in $W^{1,p}(-1,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068189/weak-derivative-of-ux-x-not-belong-in-w1-p-1-1)

In short, it is easy to see that the weak derivative of $|x|$ (defined on $(-1, 1)$) is the function $g(x)$ which is equal to $-1$ if $x \in (-1, 0)$ and $1$ if $x \in (0,1)$.

The accepted solution presented uses the density of the certain type of functions in $L^{p}(-1, 1)$, but I have another (potentially incorrect) solution in mind. In particular, is it true that weak and strong derivatives coincide *pointwise, i.e. wherever both exist?* We know that for $f \in C^{1}(-1, 1)$ the weak and strong derivative coincide on all of $(-1, 1$). But is it true in general that for any function in $L^{p}(-1,1)$ its weak derivative coincides with its strong derivative at any point at which both exist?

If that is the case, then an alternative solution to the linked problem is that the weak derivative of $g$ (as defined above) is $0$ a.e. in $(-1, 1)$, i.e. all points except $0$, where it is not defined. This shows that
$$
(\varphi(1) - \varphi(0)) + (\varphi(-1) - \varphi(0)) = \int_{-1}^{1} g' \varphi = 0
$$
for all $\varphi \in {C_{c}}^{1}(-1, 1)$, which is certainly not true. But, of course, this turns on the "lemma" I have presented above -- which I can't prove in general (other than in the $C^{1}$ case where we can integrate by parts).

Comment: It's not that the (weak...) derivative of $g$ is "not defined at $0$", but, rather, is $\delta$ (ignoring what happens outside $[-1,1]$).

Comment: @paulgarrett I see. But is my claim true?

Comment: The way to respond to your question depends strongly on context. E.g., for me, if the (distributional) derivative of a function is not locally in $L^p$, then the function itself is certainly not in $W^{1,p}$. Since the (distributional!) derivative of the (distributional) derivative of $x$ involves $\delta$, the distributional derivative of $|x|$ is not in $W^{1,p}$. This would be _my_ reaction. But you may have different groundrules. E.g., about what "weak derivative" means. Some sources have "weak derivative" have restrictions beyond being "correct, a.k.a. "distributional" deriv...

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks. Secondly, I realize that an alternative way to show that the distributional derivative of $g = 0$ a.e. would be to look at $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $\Omega = (-1, 0)$ separately. Is it true that the distributional derivative of a function with $\Omega = (-1, 1)$ must coincide (on (0,1)) with the distributional derivative of the function with $\Omega = (0,1)$?.

Answer (score 1):

OK, one sort of answer is that, yes, indeed, since both classical and distributional (and "weak") differentiability is a *local* property, and since "distributions are localizable", at every point with a nbd where a distribution's derivative is *given_by* integration against a locally $L^1$ function, that locally $L^1$ function is also the classical limit-of-difference-ratios derivative.